# How to Link the CSS in Eclipse?

Tags: java, css, eclipse, jsp

I am facing problem while linking the `css` file in `jsp` page.

My eclipse folder structure is

```
--SampleProject

  --WebContent
    --META-INF
    --resource

        --css
         style.css

        --images
         (style sheet images are present here)

        --js

    --WEB-INF
a.jsp
b.jsp
```

I want to link the css from this path resource/css/style.css in a.jsp page.

I tried all the below combinations. but no use.

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="../../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="WebContent/resource/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="resource/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and in style sheet i am linking the images by using

```
body {
    background: #c9ebff url(resource/images/left_panel.jpg) top repeat-x;

}
```

please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
body { background: #c9ebff url(../images/left_panel.jpg) top repeat-x; }
```

or

```
body { background: url(../images/left_panel.jpg); } // if linking, then add other attributes
```

> When facing these type of issues i.e files not linking .... try to use
>   FIREBUG for tracing out the browser/linking errors ... FireBug very
>   useful debugging tool.

Comment: @user2147727 first check are u able to access css file... view source of the webpage and click on css files... check css files are linked correctly? then v can link images

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist I thought that was what the OP was questioning.  How to link his css files. See title.

Answer (score -2):

Use backslash (`\`) instead of forward slash in path (`/`).

Example:

```
<link href="..\css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```